# How to create Protect folder in ubuntu server 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

In `DirectAdmin panel` I create `protect` folder for `Admin` folder, But i need create `protect` for folder in Ubuntu server 16.04 without use `DirectAdmin panel`.

For Example in `DirectAdmin` panel:

Path: /admin

file: .htaccess

```
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /home/user/domains/domain.com/.htpasswd/public_html/administrator/.htpasswd
AuthName "admin"
require valid-user
```

Path: `/home/user/domains/domain.com/.htpasswd/public_html/administrator/.htpasswd`:

```
admin:$apr1$Zbp5WV.h$wmBNMkeSuUd./eL9OFwxX.
```

Picture:

[image]

......

Now how to create `protect` for folder in Ubuntu server 16.04?

Comment: Please be a bit more clear!

Comment: Hi @George , Edit my question.

Comment: your referring to `apache server`?

Comment: No! add picture in my question.

Comment: Ok I get you now one one moment will post an answer.

Comment: I have added an answer please check it out, I believe that's what you were looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options to do this:

1. Using the `htpasswd` commmand, and
2. Using the `.htaccess` file

Option 1:

1. When using the `htpasswd` command for the first time we use it like this:

   ```
   sudo htpasswd -c /etc/apache2/.htpasswd sammy

   # you wil be asked for password for user sammy
   # content of .htpasswd would be
   # sammy:$apr1$lzxsIfXG$tmCvCfb49vpPFwKGVsuYz.
   # another_user:$apr1$p1E9MeAf$kiAhneUwr.MhAE2kKGYHK.
   ```
2. for additional users leave out the `-c` argument

   ```
   sudo htpasswd /etc/apache2/.htpasswd another_user
   ```
3. Configure apache to check this file (.htpasswd):

   a. Open virtual host file for the domain in question:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf


   <VirtualHost *:80>
           ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
           DocumentRoot /var/www/html
           ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
           CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

           <Directory "/var/www/html/MyDomain/protect_folder">
                   AuthType Basic
                   AuthName "Restricted Content"
                   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
                   Require valid-user
           </Directory>
   </VirtualHost>
   ```

   b. Restart apache:

   ```
     sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Option 2: Using `.htaccess file`

1. Find the  block for the /var/www directory that holds the document root. 
   Turn on .htaccess processing by changing the AllowOverride directive within that block 
   from "None" to "All"

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

   <Directory /var/www/>
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride All
         Require all granted
   </Directory>

     # save and close
   ```
2. Add `.htaccess` file to `protect folder`:

   ```
   sudo nano /var/www/html/.htaccess

   # Add the following
   AuthType Basic
   AuthName "Restricted Content"
   AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
   Require valid-user
   ```
3. Restart apache:

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

**Note:**

1. Advantage of `.htpasswd file`:

   Apache will not re-read these files on every request that involves the directory, 
       which helps performance.
2. Advantage of `.htaccess file`:

   If you can not modify the `Virtual host file` this is the
      right choice
3. You don't have to use `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` use any virtual host you may have created
4. This is for a `VPS` you control, for shared hosting setting it up will be host dependent and is usually automated **seek advice** from **customer care** at your shared host.

Source:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04